# How can I create an ASP.NET site that has a custom authentication/session timeout for each user?

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, session-timeout

I am trying to build an ASP.NET site that allows each user to set their own session timeout value.  Basically from the user's perspective if they set their timeout value to 30 then that means that after 30 minutes of inactivity they are required to re-authenticate.  If they set their timeout value to 0 then that means that they can leave the browser open as long as they want and their session never expires - they never have to re-authenticate.  This is different than "remember me" functionality.  If they close their browser they will have to re-authenticate.

Currently I am using Forms Authentication in my application and I have one object that I am storing in ASP.NET session.  This object is a custom User object that has a number of different pieces of information about the current user.

What code would I need to write so that after successful login, the system has the proper authentication ticket and the proper session expiration value?  I keep thinking I have this working and then I notice weird time outs where the system seems to think I am authenticated but my session has expired.

Currently on my login page I am using an ASP.NET login control.  I have custom code in the Login_Authenticate event to authorize the user.  Then I have the following code in the Login_LoggedIn event to set the auth ticket.

```
HttpCookie _authCookie = Response.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
FormsAuthenticationTicket _oldAuthTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(_authCookie.Value);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Remove(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName);
FormsAuthenticationTicket _newAuthTicket;
if(myObject.LoginTimeout > 0)
{
    _newAuthTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(_oldAuthTicket.Version, _oldAuthTicket.Name, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(myObject.LoginTimeout), _oldAuthTicket.IsPersistent, _oldAuthTicket.UserData, FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
}
else
{
    _newAuthTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(_oldAuthTicket.Version, _oldAuthTicket.Name, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddYears(10), _oldAuthTicket.IsPersistent, _oldAuthTicket.UserData, FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
}
string _encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(_newAuthTicket);
_authCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, _encryptedTicket);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(_authCookie);
```

Answer (score 1):

You will want to pick some kind of arbitary expiration, say 2 months from now. Set your forms authentication to use that as the value (also make sure the forms auth ticket expiration is set that high too).

At this point you would want to write a custom Http Module (or use the global.asax) and either at the beginning of a request you check the FormAuth ticket to see when it was issued, query the data store to get the users session timeout. Compare the difference between those (might want to consider storing a time span) and if the user is outside the session length to call `FormsAuthentication.SignOut()`

I created a similar system for a custom active security token service for single sign on using this basic idea.

Comment: Hmmm...so instead of actually setting the Forms Authentication timeout differently for each user, you have it hard coded to some very large value.  Then you sign the user out manually if need be.  Wouldn't you be querying the data store on every request?

Comment: Yes you're correct I query the datastore on every request. I implement an edge cache on each of the relying party sites for the user record and it checks the edge cache before promoting to a database query and hitting the remote STS server.

Comment: What about ASP.NET session?  I seem to be having problems with ASP.NET session and Forms Authentication getting "out of sync".  Ideally I would not want the ASP.NET session to expire either.

Comment: @Corey Burnett - The Signout method only wipes the auth cookie. The session cookie is left untouched and thus if the user turns around an logs in after you manually log them out, they'll have their session data. However, be mindful of the session timeout which is separate from the auth timeout.

Comment: Actually my problem is the reverse.  I have situations where the authentication ticket is still valid, but the session has timed out.  So then when I go to a page I get errors because there is nothing in session.

Comment: You definitely want sessions to expire. Use persistent data stores when you need persistent storage. Session is most useful for storing like a user changes the grid size from 25 items to 100 items. That after a browser session it resets back to 25. Data you store in session you should want to, or atleast expect to continuously reset. If you don't want that, the solution is not to use the session for that data, not to make session be persistent.